# Android Space evenly horizontally

Tags: android

I am trying to create a "toolbar control" in Android.
I want to add let's say 4 buttons that are evenly spaced horizontally.
First thing that came into my mind was to create a horizontal linear layout and add the buttons with 0 width and equal weight. Then the buttons will be centered in each slice of 1/4 width. This is not what I want.
I want the first and the last button to stick to the margin and the rest of them to be equally aligned in the remaining space.
Like in this image:

[image: space evenly android controls]
.
The buttons are the blue squares. The container is the red rectangle. It should fill its parent.

Comment: subclass LinearLayout and override onLayout(), there you can measure the children and place them as you wish, set margins etc...

Comment: you can use layout:weight. make the parent's layout weight 4, then for each blue square you set the weight to 1 and combine that with margins and padding

Answer (score 2):

Try out this in your layout file;

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.175"
        android:text="Button" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.175"
        android:text="Button" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.175"
        android:text="Button" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.175"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Using `weightSum` is a great technique. However, for the OP, if you're targeting ICS+ devices only, you may want to use the lightweight [`Space`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html) widget, instead of `View`.

Comment: The buttons will be 0.175*parent_width wide. I want exactly 10dp. Is this possible?

Comment: Please try setting android:maxWidth="10dp" for each of the buttons. Also set android:layout_weight="1" and android:weightSum="7".

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. It's similar to what Sameer answered but I removed the weight in the buttons as I found it useless:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```